# ¿Cómo mejorar el movimiento del cursor?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo un programa que me genera una gráfica mediante la lectura de un archivo.

He introducido un cursor que se mueve a través de la gráfica para poder ver las coordenadas en las que me encuentro.

El problema es que cuando la gráfica es muy extensa el cursor va muy lento. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna otra manera para mejorar la actualización del cursor o si es posible que en lugar de las dos líneas del cursor aparezca una sola línea vertical y un punto que se moviese a través de la gráfica.

El problema viene que al tener gráficas de 200mil o más puntos es imposible mover el cursor.

Dejo una parte del código de como genero y actualizo los cursores con un ejemplo de un coseno. Gracias.

```
from math import *
import numpy as np

ejeXCH=[]
CH = []
for i in range(20000):
    CH.append(cos(i))
for i in range(len(CH)):
    ejeXCH.append(i)
fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(ejeXCH, CH)
lx = ax.axhline(color='k',linewidth=1)  # linea horizontal
ly = ax.axvline(color='k',linewidth=1)    #linea vertical del cursor
txt=ax.text(0.8, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes) #texto para representar las coordenadas

def cursor(event):
    try:
        ly.set_xdata(event.xdata)#actualizacion de cursor
        x= round(event.xdata)
        indx = min(np.searchsorted(ejeXCH, x), len(ejeXCH) - 1)
        y = CH[indx]
        lx.set_ydata(y)
        txt.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.3f' % (event.xdata, y))#actualizacion de texto
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    except:
        None
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', cursor)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Este tipo de problemas se suele abordar reduciendo la cantidad de datos a mostrar. Por ejemplo puedes resamplearlos. Otra opción es en lugar de matplotlib usar alguna otra librería de visualización (como bokeh) que plotee usando javascript, las cuales suelen hacer automáticamente ese tipo de resampling según el nivel de zoom, y que ya incorporan el tipo de inspectores de datos que tú estabas tratando de programar.